# HaxeFlixel - Hello World with android wont start / turn off

Tags: android, haxe, openfl, haxeflixel, lime-haxe

Im trying to build hello world in haxeflixel for android. So there is deal : i create new project build it and then send it into device and run it.  **After few seconds app turns off.** Its my first android app ever, so basically im pretty lost. I added only one line in create method in MenuState class: `add(new FlxText(100, 100, 0, "hello world"));`. My thinking was that i need to change resolution but after few tries nothing change. My current res is `800 x 480`. 
I think that its in AndroidManifest.xml. But there should be default manifest if i understand it correctly.
So where is catch ? What i did wrong ? Thanks for tips. 
Edit : forgot mention that spash logo didnt appear either. And its turned on in code

pastebin with logcat (splited on two)

[link 1](http://pastebin.com/4awh5Dr6)
[link 2](http://pastebin.com/qDMaJ7h1)

or maybe working hello world sample could be handy. From that point i can look for my mistakes.

Comment: With the Android device connected to your computer type ```adb logcat``` at your command prompt and then run the app to get info about the crash. The problem may be due to a bug in a version of lime/openfl/haxeflixel you are using, so you should use ```haxelib set``` to try building the app using different versions of these.

Comment: im trying to read logcat but as i said : my first android app. Tryed change versions, same problem

Comment: Yes, please put the relevant logcat output on pastebin and link to it, then we can work out why it is closing.

Comment: added links to pastebin

Comment: The crash is in ```liblime.so``` and so is probably a low-level crash. You could also try building the ```flixel-demos``` and seeing if they crash too. If building against older versions of ```lime```, ```flixel``` or ```openfl``` really make no difference, it could be an issue with your device.

Comment: So i reinstalled haxe. Now its not restarting, splash logo appear but there is no graphics in actual game state. Just black screen.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
add(new FlxText(0, 0, 100, "hello world"));
```

Just under `super.create();`. Maybe it solves the problem.

Comment: no that isnt issue. I forgot mention that haxeflixel splash logo didnt appear either

Comment: oh, okay. Can't help you yet, not much experiences with HaxeFlixel :/